# How to count the number of words in a string

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I count the number of words in a string with Snowflake? I cant seem to find anything on Google directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this.  It assumes that a space separates every word:

```
SELECT ARRAY_SIZE(SPLIT(string,' '));
```

Answer (score 2):

This UDF will handle punctuation, multiple spaces between words, line breaks, etc. It's not completely bulletproof, but should work for most use cases.

```
create or replace function WORD_COUNT(SENTENCE string)
returns number
language sql
as
$$
    array_size(split(trim(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(SENTENCE, '[^A-Za-z0-9]', ' '), '[ ]{2,}', ' ')), ' '))
$$;

select word_count('The quick  brown--fox jumps over.the;lazy?dog.');
```